# java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "2018-05-23T06:39:37+0000"

Tags: java, android, date, simpledateformat, formatexception

I'm trying to create a `Date` from a `String` I receive from the server. The `String` is:

> 2018-05-23T06:39:37+0000

So the correct format should be:

> yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ

Here is my code:

```
String createdDate = comment.getCreatedDateTime();
SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ", Locale.US);
try {
    Date parsedDate = simpleDateFormat.parse(createdDate);
    createdDate = parsedDate.toString();
} catch (ParseException ex) {
    ex.printStackTrace();
}
mCommentDate.setText(createdDate);
```

I don't know if there is any way to do this, because after that I would like to parse again to the next format:

> dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm

I've tried to parse the original `String` using this last format directly but I'm getting the same exception.

Any suggestion?

Comment: Create another `SimpleDateFormat` instance with new format and call 'format' method with the date you parsed already.

Comment: Why do you have the  `S`s in `yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ`? your string doesn't contain milis

Comment: Sorry, it was not `hh/MM/yyyy`, it is `dd/MM/yyyy`. My mistake.

Comment: What I understand is that you're trying to create a Date object out of a String date, right? For the SDF to consider parsing the String to an appropriate Date object you need to specify the correct pattern-format, which in your case is slightly wrong! If that gets rectified you can correctly obtain your Date object...

Comment: As an aside consider throwing away the long outmoded and notoriously troublesome `SimpleDateFormat` and friends, and adding [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) to your Android project in order to use `java.time`, the modern Java date and time API. It is so much nicer to work with. `OffsetDateTime.parse("2018-05-23T06:39:37+0000", DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("uuuu-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssxx"))`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, the first mistake (as you've pointed) is I didn't have milliseconds on the original `String`.

After removing "SSS" from the `simpleDateFormat` it works like a charm. So this is the final code:

```
String createdDate = comment.getCreatedDateTime();
SimpleDateFormat defaultDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ", Locale.getDefault());
try {
    Date parsedDate = defaultDateFormat.parse(createdDate);
    SimpleDateFormat finalDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm", Locale.getDefault());
    createdDate = finalDateFormat.format(parsedDate);
} catch (ParseException ex) {
    ex.printStackTrace();
}
mCommentDate.setText(createdDate);
```

Answer (score 2):

I see you've solved your own problem with a little help from the comments, however I would suggest you seriously consider [LocalDate](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html), as the older Date classes are quite troublesome at times.

In fact, as your incoming value has a `TimeZone`, you'll need to use [ZonedDateTime](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html) to parse your input.

```
String createdDate = "2018-05-23T06:39:37+0000";
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ");
ZonedDateTime localDate = ZonedDateTime.parse(createdDate, formatter);
System.out.println(localDate.format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm")));
```

**Output:**

> 23/05/2018 06:39

Comment: Android API 26 is needed to use `ZonedDateTime`, but I'll keep for other projects. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: The same functionality is available for lower-level Android since the classes of `java.time` have been backported. What you need is [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP), the Android edition of the backport. More in [this question: How to use ThreeTenABP in Android Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922754/how-to-use-threetenabp-in-android-project).

Comment: The variable name `localDate` seems unfortunate here. A left-over from an early version of the code?

Comment: @OleV.V. yes - feel free to change the variable name - it was from similar code I had already.

Answer (score 1):

The given input  date `String` format

> 2018-05-23T06:39:37+0000

is incorrect so that you are getting `ParseException` since **millisecond(SSS)** part is missing from your date format yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.**SSS**Z

So please try with

> 2018-05-23T06:39:37.235-0530

so below code should work

```
String createdDate = comment.getCreatedDateTime();
SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ", Locale.US);
    try {
        Date parsedDate = simpleDateFormat.parse(createdDate);
        createdDate = parsedDate.toString();
        System.out.println(parsedDate.toString());
    } catch (ParseException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
mCommentDate.setText(createdDate);
```

Comment: I don't think OP can change the incoming value.

Comment: @notyou: i dont understand what you are coming to say

Comment: OP gets a value like so `2018-05-23T06:39:37+0000` but you say to use `2018-05-23T06:39:37.235-0530` but I would imagine they can't change that value.

Comment: @notyou: i just given a example with 2018-05-23T06:39:37.235-0530(here -0530 mention that IST timezont). but 2018-05-23T06:39:37.000+0000(GST timezont) also will work perfectly.

Comment: @notyou: anyway i dont changed in his input to the code.